# tikz foreach used for number in filename for addplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, foreach

I have quite a few tables generated which I want to plot in the same TikZ figure (using pgfplots). I am currently trying to use a foreach loop to plot them all, but it is only plotting the *last* figure.

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,legend pos=north west,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    legend style={draw=none}]
    \def \N {14}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\N} {
        \addplot[smooth,magenta] plot[]file{tablerev/airyratio\N.dat};
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

I'm not sure what is causing this behavior. Apparently using the `\N` works as part of a filename, and if I plot them separately they will plot, so why is it not showing all 14 plots?

Comment: should the `\N` in the `\addplot` be a `\i`?

Comment: ...yes, oops...x_x

Now how to close this question?

Comment: I believe there should be a close link near the `share`, `edit` etc links at the bottom of your post. I can't help out with this as its above my reputation grade!

Comment: glad you got it fixed :) I'll flag it for a moderator, and will vote to close (you need `\geq 3000` rep to vote)